# Where should custom vmware-tools scripts go

Tags: vmware-tools

I have installed the VMWare Tools into a test Ubuntu guest, and it's created the standard scripts as expected:

```
poweroff-vm-default
poweron-vm-default
resume-vm-default
suspend-vm-default
```

I add some custom actions to the scripts, but it says in the top of the file

```
##########################################################################
# DO NOT modify this file directly as it will be overwritten the next
# time the VMware Tools are installed.
##########################################################################
```

So where should the custom scripts go, if I'm not supposed to modify these ones?

```
scriptsdir="`dirname $0`/scripts/`basename $0`.d"
if [ -d "$scriptsdir" ]; then
    for scriptfile in "$scriptsdir"/*; do
        [ -x "$scriptfile" ] && "$scriptfile" poweron-vm
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some information on [creating custom VMWare Tools scripts](http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Working_with_VMware_Tools_Scripts_and_Power_States#Creating_Custom_VMware_Tools_Scripts).

From phrases such as "enter the path and name of the script file" and "use the Browse feature to navigate to and select the new custom script" I infer that any location is suitable. I would use `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Not very helpful

Comment: @user705142: The OP apparently found it useful since he accepted it. However, I've tried to improve my answer a little. You didn't say how you found it unhelpful, but I hope you find the change at least a slight improvement. And yet someone upvoted it just after you made your comment and before I edited it.

Comment: If you're adding in scripts manually like this guy's doing they need to be in simple subdirectories such as /script/resume-vm-default.d/. Your link is only helpful if using the GUI, which this guy isn't (nor me, who came across this via google).

Answer (score 2):

They go in (ToolsDir)/script/resume-vm-default.d/, (ToolsDir)/script/poweroff-vm-default.d/ directories.

They also need to be executable.